# Why can't I return a normal map reference with a transparent functor?

Tags: c++, functor

This code works:

```
class MyObj {};

class MyData {
 public:
  using tMyMap = std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>>;

  const tMyMap& get_normal() const;
  const tMyMap& get_reverse() const;

 private:
  std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>> _normal;

  std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>, std::less<uint64_t>> _reverse;
};

const MyData::tMyMap& get_normal() const { return _normal; }
const MyData::tMyMap& get_reverse() const { return _reverse; }
```

But clang-tidy recommends that I use a transparent functor and change `std::less<uint64_t>` to `std::less<>` in my declaration of `_reverse`. Unfortunately, when I do that, the code doesn't compile anymore:

```
test_map.cpp: In member function ‘const tMyMap& MyData::get_reverse() const’:
test_map.cpp:20:60: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const tMyMap& {aka const std::map<long unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<MyObj> >&}’ from expression of type ‘const std::map<long unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>, std::less<void> >’
 const MyData::tMyMap& MyData::get_reverse() const { return _reverse; }
```

That error message is from g++, but clang gives me a similar error.

Why is the typed functor okay, but the transparent functor doesn't compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map`'s default comparator is `std::less<KeyType>`.

This means that

```
std::map<uint64_t, T>
```

and

```
std::map<uint64_t, T, std::less<uint64_t>>
```

are the same type, but

```
std::map<uint64_t, T, std::less<>>
```

is a different type because `std::less<uint64_t>` and `std::less<>` are different types.

---

You would see the same issue if `_normal` and `_reverse` were actually the reverse of each other.  I assume you actually meant to declare `_reverse` as

```
std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>, std::greater<uint64_t>> _reverse;
```

so that it's ordered in the opposite direction from `_normal`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the comparison function is part of the type of an instance of the `std::map` template. The default value for the comparison function used by an `std::map<K, T>` is `std::less<T>`. So

```
std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>, std::less<uint64_t>>
```

and

```
std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>>
```

happen to be the same type (the second version will use the default argument for the comparison function, which comes out to be `std::less<uint64_t>`). However, if you use `std::less<>` (which is equivalent to `std::less<void>`) as your comparison function for `_reverse`, then the types of `_normal` and `_reverse` will not turn out the same anymore. Only `_normal` will still be of type `tMyMap`, which uses the default comparison function, while `_reverse` will be a different, unrelated type.

If the purpose of `MyData` is simply to hold these two maps, you might want to consider just turning it into a struct:

```
struct MyData {
  std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>> normal;
  std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>, std::less<>> reverse;
};
```

Or just use `auto` to avoid having to repeat the type of each map

```
class MyData {
public:
  const auto& get_normal() const { return _normal; }
  const auto& get_reverse() const { return _reverse; }

private:
  std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>> _normal;
  std::map<uint64_t, std::shared_ptr<MyObj>, std::less<>> _reverse;
};
```